# My Dead Escape!

Tags: ford, escape

I have a 2001 Ford Escape that has been sitting for a year & about 8mos. I took the dead battery out of it & still need to get a new battery. I also have to get at least 2 tires. What else should I do besides changing the oil/ transmission fluids?

Comment: Please provide more info. Does the car click when you attempt to start it? Does it crank (turn over) but not fire? Do electrical consumers (lights, horn) work?

Comment: "Thermostat is brand new and fans work" they haven't got that far, its in the planning stage right now

Comment: Check all the fluid levels, I don't see a reason to change trans fluid unless it is due for service. Drain the old gas out of the gas tank and put in fresh gas.